# Nodejs: unable to run expressjs and reactjs together

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I use reactjs for frontend and expressjs for backend API.

I tried this

```
   {
  "name": "carweb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "expressjs": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-countup": "^2.1.1",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-materialize": "^1.0.6",
    "react-rethinkdb": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
    "rethinkdb": "^2.3.3",
    "spicy-datatable": "^0.4.0",
    "web-storage": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "backend": "nodemon ./src/js/backend/app.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

This work perfectly. So I want to combine both commands together.

I tried:

**react-scripts start && nodemon ./src/js/backend/app.js**

This is not working.

Comment: Try `npm start && npm run backend`

Comment: Both commands start servers. Don't you need to run them in their own consoles instances?

Comment: It didnt work. React start but backend not working. When i do it separately it works.

Comment: Because the react server blocks the express server. You need to dial them up separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently
It'll allow you to do what you want. The question is "is this approach correct"